# AS3 equivalent of PHP's deg2rad

Tags: php, actionscript-3, degrees, radians

Hey all, what is the Actionscript 3 equivalent of PHP's deg2rad function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling ["ActionScript deg2rad"](http://www.google.com/search?q=actionscript+deg2rad) came up with [this](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/28728):

```
function deg2rad(degree) {
     return degree * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but don't put this in a function in production code. Odds are you'll be calling this many times a frame, so just inline it where appropriate to save costs.